# Flash Android Nougat On Rooted S7

Tags: rom-flashing, samsung-galaxy-s7, 7.0-nougat

I am wanting to flash nouget onto my device, and at the time this has no documentation about doing so. What should I do to make sure I don't screw my phone and root status up? (I am not near an expert, obviously, but I like learning :P)

Comment: Nougat is not available on the S7 yet AFAIK.

Comment: By available you mean it will break it or officially available? As I mean download a rom and flash it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ROMs are not universal - you can't just flash one from another device and call it a day.

No one has ported N for S7 yet, and due to the locked-down bootloader on the Snapdragon version / development difficulty for the Exynos version, there likely won't be any until the official one drops.

Comment: Nvm. Where is the fun in life without bleeding edge stuff. Sad news :(

Comment: @UbuntuCake The fun is in Nexus. Join the _bright_ side!

Comment: If it makes you happy, ill aim for my next phone to be a nexus. But that is a while away